# Need to convert 3d array to 2d with mean of inner array

Tags: python, numpy

I am receiving a output like the below:

```
y = [[[1,1,1,1,1,1,1] ,[2,2,2,2,2,2,2], [3,3,3,3,3,3,3]],[[4,4,4],[5, 5, 5],[6, 6, 6]]]
```

the final output should be as below:

```
Y = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
```

How to convert y to Y? [Here, the mean of the innermost array (or optionally any element) need to be used as a basic element and the final array (Y) need to be 2D, whereas the pre-final array (y) is 3D.

(I am new to numpy/python, so this question my look stupid, if any other information is needed, please let me know)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
result  = []
for i in lst:
    result.append([j[0] for j in i])
print result
```

**Result**

```
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
```

Answer (score 0):

With list comprehension:

```
y = [[[1,1,1,1,1,1,1] ,[2,2,2,2,2,2,2], [3,3,3,3,3,3,3]],[[4,4,4],[5, 5, 5],[6, 6, 6]]]

Y = [[x[0] for x in z] for z in y] # [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
```

Answer (score 0):

## double loops and insert will do the trick

```
import numpy as np
y = [[[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 ], [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2 ] ,[3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]],[[4, 4, 4],[5, 5, 5],[6, 6, 6]]]

Y = []
for l in y:         
    inner_l = []
    for sub_l in l :
        inner_l.append(np.mean(sub_l))
    Y.append(inner_l)
print Y
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 y=[[[1,1,1,1,1,1,1] ,[2,2,2,2,2,2,2], [3,3,3,3,3,3,3]],[[4,4,4],[5, 5, 5],[6, 6, 6]]]
 rslt = []
 for x in y:
     lst=[]
     for m in x:
         lst.append([m[0]])
     rslt.append(lst)
```

**Result:**

```
rslt = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
```